# How to use FastAPI to fill HTML page from HTTP request

Tags: python, websocket, bots, fastapi, rasa

Im trying to fill a website (chatbot widget) using FastAPI. I want the page to show me a first message automatically, then I type something, that text is sent via POST request to Rasa server. Then it should display the response back in frontend.

This is my index.html:

```
<html>
<div id="rasa-chat-widget" data-websocket-url="http://localhost:5005"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@rasahq/rasa-chat" type="application/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

This is some of my FastAPI code

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def index():
    path = "/path"
    return HTMLResponse(content=pathlib.Path(path).read_text(), status_code=200)

@app.post("/parse")
def post_attempt(text: Text):
    body = {"text": text.text,"message_id": str(uuid.uuid4())}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    url = "http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"
    return requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

However I get no reply from Rasa server on the frontend, I just see the chat widget when opening webpage and am able to type, but Rasa is not returning a response and showing on html page. What am I missing? thanks

Comment: `requests.post` is not a websocket...

Comment: Perhaps you want to import and create a WebSocket object - https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

Comment: thanks @OneCricketeer thats helpful. I had a look but not sure how to implement it. I am guessing a function like async def websocket_endpoint(), but how do I POST and GET data?

Comment: Websockets do not work with POST/GET methods, only send/receive. I'm not familiar with this "Rasa" thing

Comment: ok thanks anyway @OneCricketeer I'll what I can do with send/receive

Comment: You should use the Rasa [rest](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/#restinput) channel, not the chat widget.

Comment: @SeattleStephens what to you mean? The rest channel is used inside Rasa application, but my goal is populate the HTML for user front-end UI. Let me know if you have any suggestion thanks